# Legality of commiting a crime, car theft

Tags: criminal-law, is-x-legal

I am interested in knowing about the legality of committing a crime in a situation that disable another crime from happening while protecting one's life or property.

For example: A man a has a car. There is an evidence of a different man's intention, man B, to steal a car to the man A. The man B has to use his car to get to the place of residence of man A. Can man A legally steal man's B car to disable the intended car theft from happening?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't kill somebody because they threaten me verbally to stop my murder from possibly happening...

Comment: I think the crime would have to be *clear and imminent* and the actor would (largely) have to have no other recourse to thwart it.  For instance, man A could park the car 4 blocks away and Man B would be unlikely to find it. Or if it is a common car, remove distinguishing marks like bumper stickers and park it 2 blocks away, and it would be lost among the numerous other gray Camrys on the street.

Answer (score 5):

"Necessity" is a defense against criminal prosecution in many jurisdictions. However, what counts as "necessary" is situation dependent. The essence of an action being "necessary" is an action is necessary if there is no other means of preventing a crime. In your scenario, there are many non-criminal alternative means of preventing the theft, such as calling the police, moving your car, or locking it, so stealing a person's car is not necessary. The conclusion that a crime "will be committed, but for..." also has to be clearly supported by reason.

Comment: Equally important, the other crime you are preventing must be imminent.